# how to find/replace in a json file using jtc?

Tags: json, jq, mongoimport, jtc

I have the file below. Using [jtc](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) how to I replace all occurrences of `"value": 1234.56` with `"value": {"$numberDecimal":"1234.56"}`; that is, wrap the numbers. This is for `mongoimport`, I want to require values to be imported as decimals not floats.

Or maybe there's a better solution using `jq`?

An example file:

```
{
  "data": {
    "slice": [
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "foo"
        },
        "value": 1.0
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "bar"
        },
        "value": 2.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ SoniaHamilton, I'm not sure I understand the ask, you're showing the example of wrapping a value of `1234.56` - which is a float value, but then you're stating you would like value to be imported as decimals. Could you clarify, or provide an example of the expected output JSON?

Comment: Hi @Dmitry. Mongo's NumberDecimal format accepts either strings or floats in its constructor https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberdecimal. To do this you replace 1234.56 with {"$numberDecimal":"1234.56"} in the JSON file being imported by mongoimport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then with the latest `jtc` build you can do it like this:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[value]:<>N:' -u'{"$numberDecimal":"{}"};' -tc
{
   "data": {
      "slice": [
         {
            "source": { "id": "foo" },
            "value": { "$numberDecimal": "1.0" }
         },
         {
            "source": { "id": "bar" },
            "value": { "$numberDecimal": "2.0" }
         }
      ]
   }
}
bash $
```

and if you like to do an in-place file modifications then use `-f`:

```
bash $ jtc -w'[value]:<>N:' -u'{"$numberDecimal":"{}"};' -f file.json
```

Comment: `"1": "1.0"` is not gonna work, it needs to be `"$numberDecimal": "1.0"`. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#:~:text=$numberDecimal

Comment: @oguz, ahh, I see - it was a stipulation for mongodb, not for the query, I updated the solution, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, it works. I'll put in a PR with minor doco suggestions.

Comment: Sure @SoniaHamilton, more than welcome to file a PR! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following jq program will convert numbers to JSON objects of the form `{"$numberDecimal": <STRING>}`:

```
walk(if type == "number" then {"$numberDecimal": tostring} else . end)
```

If you don't mind `1.0` becoming "1", then the above will do the job with any version of jq that has `walk`, assuming that conversion to IEEE 754 numbers does not present any issues.

Otherwise, the simplest option might be to upgrade to the current `master` version of jq (> 1.6), since this version should retain precision.